# A most important riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

I can burn, I can attack,
I can ache, I can break,
Add my head, you might find me in a shack,
Move my head, you can go on a long trek.
I can stop, I can eclipse,
I can throb, or be warming,
Remove my tail, then use those ears,
Remove my legs, its so scorching!

**What am I?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are a:

> **HEART**

*I can burn, I can attack,*
*I can ache, I can break,*

> Heartburn, heart attack, heartache, heartbreak.

*Add my head, you might find me in a shack,*

> Add another 'H' (its 'head', or first letter) to get **HEARTH**, the floor of a fireplace (which might be used to warm a shack).

*Move my head, you can go on a long trek.*

> Move the 'H' to the end instead to get **EARTH**, a planet you can travel for thousands of miles...

*I can stop, I can eclipse, I can throb, or be warming,*

> You can stop a heart, have a [*Total Eclipse of the Heart*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Eclipse_of_the_Heart) (if you're Bonnie Tyler), be a heartthrob, or be heart-warming.

*Remove my tail, then use those ears,*

> Remove the tail (i.e. last letter) and you can **HEAR**.

*Remove my legs, its so scorching!*

> Remove the penultimate letter ('legs'), and you have **HEAT**.

As for the title:

> We've really got to the **HEART** of the matter when we realise what a *vital* organ it is!

Comment: I cannot say I wasn't expecting this, but wow, the Stivster do be solving fast

Comment: @Auribouros Just lucky timing to come on-site within seconds of you posting! :)

Comment: @Stiv is honestly just hacking into Auribouros's computer to see the answer. HOW do you solve it so fast holy... (aint the fastest solver in the west anymore, its in the fastest solver in the universe)

Comment: @DialFrost I do agree that Stiv is fast and skillful, but this time I think it was just too easy. I imagine many people (like me) suspected the answer after line 1. Lines 1 and 2 just give it away. I recommended their deletion but OP wanted to keep.